# Database versions for Oozie

Tags: oracle, cloudera, oozie

I would like to change my Oozie installation from a MySQL db to an Oracle db.
My cluster is running CDH 5.4.7 with Oozie 4.1. The Oracle db that I have access to is version 12c.

In the [Cloudera documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/rn_consolidated_pcm.html#cdh_cm_supported_db) it states that Oracle db 12c is only supported by Cloudera Manager and CDH 5.6 and newer.
My question is therefore: is there any reason why my Oozie installation should not be able to use this database, even through Cloudera components do not support it? In the [Oozie documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/AG_Install.html#Database_Configuration) it does not state anything version related, as far as I have found.

I am lacking a non-production system to test this on, but looking into setting one up currently.

Any answers, including speculation, are appreciated.

If any information is missing, I will gladly append.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oozie inside CDH5.4.7 is using a [quite old OpenJPA version, 2.2.2](https://github.com/cloudera/oozie/blob/cdh5-4.1.0_5.4.7/pom.xml#L102).
[OpenJPA 2.2.2](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.2/apache-openjpa/docs/manual.html#d5e17480) does not support Oracle 12c.
However CDH5.8.0 still using [OpenJPA 2.2.2](https://github.com/cloudera/oozie/blob/cdh5-4.1.0_5.8.0/pom.xml#L104), so my guess it that is will probably work but was never tested. Make sure to create a backup of your DB before the migration. Also, you might try the DB migration tool developed in [OOZIE-2632](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2632)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I tried installing Oozie using an Oracle 12c on a CDH5.5 installation, at it seems to work. Hopefully it will be the same for 5.4, as they are both unsupported according to Cloudera documentation.